# Need help comparing an array against a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I can't seem to get this right. Basically if the value of a select list is either "USA", "CAN", or "MEX" it should return true. any other value should return false. This only returns true if the value is "USA"

```
$.validator.addMethod(
"ReutersNA",
function(value, element) {
    var selectedCountry = $("#Country").val();
    var NorthAmerica = new Array("USA","CAN","MEX");
    if($.inArray(selectedCountry,NorthAmerica)) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Cannot select Reuters News outside of North America."
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Jquery expert but this is from the [Jquery Site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) for .inArray, You should be aware that **inArray returns the index** and:

> "Because JavaScript treats 0 as
>   loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 ==
>   false, but 0 !== 
>       false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we
>   need to check
>       if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1."

Therefore you should be trying **!= -1** or **>-1** in your if statement as follows

```
if($.inArray(selectedCountry,NorthAmerica) != -1)
```

or

```
if($.inArray(selectedCountry,NorthAmerica) > -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. using >0 caused it to return false on USA the first(0) item in the array. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
return $.inArray(selectedCountry,NorthAmerica) != -1;
```

`$.inArray` returns the index where it's found, or -1.  The index 0 is falsy, so in that case it went to the else clause and returned true.  For everything else, it returned false.

Comment: Yes, I see that removes the if statement, I just couldn't get it to work! Id be very interested in knowing how, smaller code is always better!

Comment: @Dirty, I had a typo initially.  `==` instead of `!=`.  This version should be correct, and I consider it more readable.

Comment: I apologize, but I cannot get 
$.validator.addMethod(
 "ReutersNA",
 function(value, element) {
  var selectedCountry = $("#Country").val();
  var NorthAmerica = new Array("USA","CAN","MEX");
  return $.inArray(selectedCountry,NorthAmerica) == -1;

 }, "Cannot select Reuters News outside of North America."
 ); 

to work

Comment: @Dirty, I meant my original code, which had `==`, was wrong.  My current answer (with `!=`), should be correct.

Comment: @Josh K - I need to add in there to only do this if "#IQBAS, #IQPRE" are :checked

Answer (score 0):

It returns the index.  and your having it return false if it did find it!

try changing it to this:

```
if($.inArray(selectedCountry,NorthAmerica) > 0) {
    return true;
} 
else{

   return false;
}
```